# Mixed Content on XMLHttp request

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, oauth-2.0

I'm currently working with the Bungie API and am having some trouble getting OAuth Tokens from a POST request. I am currently using javascript with XMLHttpRequest to make the post and handle the response, but every time I send a post, it gives me a Mixed Content page even though both the website I am hosting and the API endpoint is https. I've been searching everywhere and all I can find is that I either need to secure my site (even though my site has an SSL certificate) or alter the URL in the post by removing or adding a slash (I've done both many times). Any advice or ideas are appreciated, thanks!

Code:

```
var url="https://www.bungie.net/Platform/App/OAuth/Token";

https.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(this.readyState==4){
        if (this.status==200) {
            console.log(this.responseText);
        }
        else if (this.status==400) {
            console.error("Bad Request (400) Response: " + this.responseText);
        }
        else if (this.status==401) {
            console.error("Unauthorized (401) Response: " + this.responseText);
        }
        else {
            console.error("There was a Problem: " + this.responseText);
        }
    }
}
https.open('POST', url, true);
https.setRequestHeader("X-API-Key","e76XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
https.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
https.setRequestHeader("Authorization", authHeader);
https.send(data);
```

Error Message:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://mywebsiteurl.com/callbacks.html? 
code=08fcbde4d71019d1d795a1c1dd79be67' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure 
XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://www.bungie.net/Platform/App/OAuth/Token/'. This request has been 
blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Comment: The error has nothing to do with certificates or slashes. It says you're trying to access an `http:` URL from an `https:` page. The URL you show in the question is `https:`, are you sure it's like that in the real code?

Comment: @Barmar I believe so, I've checked the documentation for the API and it says the URL for the POST starts with https: and is exactly that Bungie link, that's why I'm so confused about all of this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with the bungle.net server. It's redirecting from HTTPS to HTTP, and Chrome is then blocking this because it violates the restriction against mixed content.

I don't think there's anything you can do in your code to override the restriction.